# Fast link change in a html file

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have an **html** page with a lot of **links** in it. I moved the content to which the link points to another storage location, so I got a new link. Is there a way to quickly replace links on my website? There are a lot of files involved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got it right, but I assume that this is what you are looking for:

When you have installed an code / text editor you can use search and replace to replace the links.
Another way is REGEX when the links are variable...